# How to capture an accurate position of this square and set it there when page reloads?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

On this jsfiddle, one can move a square around. 
http://jsfiddle.net/helpme128/mafaotjf/1/

When the mouse button is released, the x,y coordinates appear on the console.

```
stop: function (e) {
    console.log("STOPPING");
    console.log(e.clientX); 
    console.log(e.clientY);
```

I then take the numerical contents of `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` and replace them on the following code;

```
    startX: 200,
    startY: 150,
```

For the above case, `e.clientX` is equal to 200 and `e.clientY` is equal to 150. However, `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` is not an accurate location. When the page reloads, the white square will be shifted. How to get a more accurate x,y coordinate location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` are the coordinates of the mouse cursor. Not the white square.

And when the user start to drag, the cursor is not in the center of the white square (it can be anywhere in the square).

If you want accurate coordinate, you'll have to take the coordinates of the white square directly.